# How to slide-out in css before an element disappears?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to create a burger menu and I'm having trouble when I want to create the sliding-out animation.

The slide effect works well when the bar appears.
[image]
But the slide effect doesn't work in the other sens.
My bar just instantly disappears and not doing the slide effect.
[image]

Could you help me pls ?

This is my scss:

```css
.bar{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30em;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    padding-left: 7em;
    
    animation: slide-in 0.3s forwards;
  
    @keyframes slide-in {
      from {
        right: -100%; // Start at its normal position
      }
      to {
        right: 0; // End offscreen to the right
      }
    }

    &.disappear{
        animation: slide-out 0.3s forwards;
        @keyframes slide-out {
            from {
              right: 0; // Start at its normal position
            }
            to {
              right: -100%; // End offscreen to the right
            }
          }
        &:before{
            right: -100%;
        }
    }
}
```

The react component:

```js
export default function BurgerBar()  {
  return (
    <div className={styles.bar}>
        <ul className={styles.listTitle}>
            <li>
                <Link href='/projet' className={styles.title}>
                    <img src="/icons/laptop.png" alt="laptop" className={styles.iconTitle}/>
                    PROJETS
                </Link>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
export default function Navbar() {

  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.navbar}>
        <Link href='/'>
          <img src="/icons/circle.png" alt="circle" className={styles.circle}/>
        </Link>
        <BurgerButton active={active} setActive={setActive}/>
      </div>
      { active ? <BurgerBar/> : '' }
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is removing the burger bar node before its slide-out animation completes.

Therefore, instead of unmounting the component:

```js
{ active ? <BurgerBar/> : '' }
```

…pass the boolean to `<BurgerBar active={active} />`

And in that component, use the `open` vs `closed` css class accordingly.

Optionally and recommended, in `BurgerBar` use `onTransitionEnd` to call function in the parent to unmount it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I still have a problem with onTransitionEnd.